# What's the point of camel-case-navigation?

Tags: editor, editor-navigation

I heavily use CTRL+ to jump between tokens in code (the `_`s are the navigation points):

```
_fooBar _+ _barFoo_;
```

Some editors, like the one in the current version of QtCreator, have (by default or optionally) camel case navigation, which goes like this:

```
_foo_Bar _+ _bar_Foo_;
```

What is the rationale behind this? I remember some people back in school saying "cool" and "fancy", but is that the whole story? I do not think it is cool, I find it very annoying actually.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's a matter of personal choice, I do work with both settings, in home and in work, and I must say, that altough I think I prefer whole word jumping (1st example), 2nd one sometimes is convenient. From time to time I tent to have longer variable names, for example when I name maps<> or Dictionaries<>: `fooBarByZar`. when I want to c&p substring from this name, or jump to a word I am interested in changing, for example - renaming, it's easy to do with 2nd setting, especially when ctrl+short will not only jump 1 "subword" but also select it for copying.

Btw. the best things are simple. Simple things can be useful and complicated ones can just get into your way, so implementation simplicity is not something a feature should be judged for in my opinion.

Comment: `is not something a feature should be judged for in my opinion` -> You are right. It was more in another context (the one of the "whoa cools, how did he do it"), which you of course miss. I edited my question, thanks for the remark.

Comment: @phresnel: I've reread the original post (in response to "you ofcourse miss") and I might just understand the last sentence differently, anyways, in new context "how did they do it" - I totally agree with you. To make it clear, I also didn't want to say that this particular feature is "simple and genius", I was making general point. Cheers